# Azure SQL Create Database Status hangs

Tags: sql, azure, logging

I am trying to create a SQL Azure db (I've done this dozens of times via the portal) but the process hangs on the Create Status and a half hour later it finally quits and deletes the database.

Are their any logs I can look at to see what is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Azure portal, click on your username in the top right and select "Switch to New Portal".

On the left hand side of the new portal is a Notification tile.  Click the notification tile, which expands a blade on the right hand side.  Within that blade is a link which states "See all Audit Logs".  Click that link to see the basic logs giving more detailed information regarding processes that you have attempted from the admin portal. 
[image]

Clicking on each log entry expands into more details on individual components of each action.  See imagery below for when I created a SQL Azure Elastic DB Pool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had databases hang in a COPYING state on multiple occasions and each time have had to open a case with Microsoft to effect resolution.